# Solidify modifier isn’t working as intended - it scales outwards instead of applying thickness

Tags: modeling

Trying to create the basic shape of a phone and instead of applying thickness it just moves everything sideways and outwards. Tried to recalculate normals and nothing happened. Any help?[image]

Comment: Hello, could you add a better quality screenshot and the mesh without the modifier to see the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Modifiers act on the ‘base’ mesh and I believe it is acting on the mesh as expected but the problem is that you cannot see the effect of the solidify due to the scale of the mesh in one dimension.

In your example you are seeing the effect of thr modifier in the X and Y dimensions but not in Z -as you have scaled it to a size of zero in that direction to make it flat. This means that the solidify is also squashed flat so you see no effect.

You should select the mesh, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and choose Apply Scale. This will reset the scaling of the mesh back to 1,1,1 and your Solidify should again behave as expected.

Comment: Hi, I’m trying to add a bevel modifier before it to curve out the edges but now that’s not working after I apply scale. Any help?

Comment: I don’t understand exactly what you mean by “curve out the edges”. Perhaps start a new question from he beginning - including reference images of what you’re trying to model. It sounds like you need some pointers about the best way to go about it.